# Obtener datos desde MySql a una lista desplegable (select option)

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

Tengo este código para un select option y me consulta la base de datos y me trae el usuario logueado , pero necesito listar todos los usuarios que tengo en la base de datos.

Tampoco me lo esta almacenando en la base de datos al elegir el único usuario que me trae.

```
                       <label>
                            Usuario    
                            <?php
                                $usuarios = $database->select("usuario", [ "id_usuario", "nombre", "nick"], ["nombre" => $data['nombre']]);
                                if ($usuarios) {
                                    echo "<span class='obligatorio'>*</span><select id='usuario' name='usuario' class='width-100' required>";
                                    echo "<option></option>";
                                        foreach ($usuarios as $usuario) 
                                             echo "<option value=".$usuario['nombre'].">".$usuario['nick']."</option>";
                                    echo "</select>";
                                } else echo "<select class='width-100' disabled><option></option></select>";
                            ?>
                        </label>
```

Comment: Que extensión estas usando, esto no es Mysqli que es la extensión estándar para usa mysql en php?

Comment: Es MySql, no es ninguna extensión

Answer (score 1):

Tuve el mismo problema y mi solución fue hacer la consulta directa.. ejm

```
introducir el código aquí  $sql = "SELECT id_usuario,nombre,nick FROM usuario" ; $result = mysql_query ($sql);
  while ($usuario= mysql_fetch_row($result)){
           <option value=".$usuario[0].">".$usuario[1]."</option>"; }
```

Ya tocaría ajustar msqli según la versión de php que este manejando  e invocar la conexion a la DB !!
Suerte..

Answer (score 0):

AQUÍ CREO EL SELECT OPTION

```
<div class="units-row">
                <div class="unit-30">
                        <label>
                            Usuario    
                            <?php
                                $usuarios = $database->select("usuario", [ "id_usuario", "nombre", "nick"], ["nombre" => $data['nombre']]);
                                if ($usuarios) {
                                    echo "<span class='obligatorio'>*</span><select id='nick' name='nick' class='width-100' required>";
                                    echo "<option></option>";
                                        foreach ($usuarios as $usuario) 
                                             echo "<option value=".$usuario['nick'].">".$usuario['nick']."</option>";
                                    echo "</select>";
                                } else echo "<select class='width-100' disabled><option></option></select>";
                            ?>
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

AQUÍ LO RECIBO

```
$nick = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nick"]);
```

ACÁ LOS INSERTO EN LA BD

```
$last_user_id = $database->insert("inventario", [
    "nick"   => $nick]);
```